# How to pass Authenticate .asmx webservice(adding webreference of .asmx webservice dynamically using ScriptManager and ServiceReference)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, basic-authentication

I have a .asmx web service that I used to call from java script. I havn't added service reference instead I am adding it dynamically in default.aspx page  using below code,

```
ScriptManager manager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
if (manager != null)
{             
    manager.Services.Add(new ServiceReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServiceUrl"]));
}
```

till now it is working fine, now I need to add authentication to .asmx webservice. I have added windows authentication to  .asmx webservice. Now I need to pass credential(authenticate) to .asmx webservice. When I navigate to default.aspx, it prompt for credential. but I need to pass credential programmatically. how can I do it.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks  John for your prompt response. my application using ASMX since 2008. but now client want to add authentication.